# Is the set $S:=\{(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n : x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1\}$ open, closed or neither?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$$S:=\{(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n : x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1\}$$
For proving that this is not an open set, I took $x=(1,0,0,\dots,0)$, and said, if this is infact an open set, then $\exists r>0 \text{ s.t. } B(x,r) \subseteq S$. Now, clearly, $(1-r/2,0,0,\dots,0) \in B(x,r)$, but $ (1-r/2,0,0,\dots,0) \notin S$. Thus, $S$ isn't an open set.

But how do I prove that this is a closed set/neither ?

 For $S$ to be a closed set, all its limit points will have to be inside $S$, which seems intuitively true, but I am not able to show it explicitly. Could someone help ?

Comment: Note if $n=3$, $S$ is the surface of the unit sphere. This could help give an idea for showing $\bar{S}$ is open.

Comment: Try to realize $S$ as the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function.

Comment: Consider an arbitrary convergent sequence in $S$

Comment: @Lorago could you maybe elaborate and give an example ?

Comment: Let $\{(x_1^{(k)},\dots,x_n^{(k)})\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $S$ with limit $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\left(x_1^{(k)}\right)^2+\dots+\left(x_n^{(k)}\right)^2=1$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Taking the limit of this we get $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\left(x_1^{(k)}\right)^2+\dots+\left(x_n^{(k)}\right)^2\right)=x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2=1$, and so $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in S$. It follows that as the sequence was arbitrary, $S$ is closed.